# Can't authenticate user in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, basic-authentication

```
        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );



        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            echo 'SUCCESS!';

        } else {        

            return Redirect::to('login');

        }
```

when i run the application from browser i got this error :

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given, called in /home/srtpl17/Sites/yatin.sr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php on line 316 and defined`

What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: same problem here also.i m using laravel 4 .
modifying to 
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface is causing more errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like from your error that your User model does not implement UserInterface (the default User Model that comes with Laravel does this properly, so I'm guessing you made a custom one)

http://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php

Make sure that the User model looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

// Add your other methods here

}
```

Comment: this is a good point... can we see the definition of the User model class?  it should have something like: `class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface`

Comment: @warspite This answer is correct, make sure you implement the UserInterface and RemindableInterface, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php

Comment: for later comacrossers, the default user.php is at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php now

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what `userdata` is defined as, but from the error message it seems like it's an instance of your `User` model class.

The `Auth::attempt()` method is looking for an array of the credentials not a model.

Answer (score 0):

This error might also  appear when you use a different model for users (example :member)
if it's the case you need to update Authentication Model and  Authentication Table in  app/config/auth.php with the appropriate model / database table.

Comment: I have done that and I still getting the same error. Any other option?