# Laravel: Know What to Implement in model

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am just about three days old in laravel, yesterday I tried creating an authentications system using eloquent, so without looking I deleted the default `User` model, and then I tried creating my own from what I had read from the documentation. After setting up every thing as I had studied and understood, I tried running my app, but whenever I enter the correct username and password I get this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given, called in dir
```

I did not know what the `EloquentUserProvider` was or where it was even coming from. My original model looked like this

```
class User extends Eloquent  {}
```

I battled with this error for the whole day (no exaggeration), But today I found out from this SO [Can't authenticate user in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723419/cant-authenticate-user-in-laravel) that it was because I had not implemented some interface, so they linked me to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php where I copied the default model I initially deleted.

I used the documentation almost through out my learning process, and no where in the documention for `authentication` and for `eloquent` did they mention that we are suppose to implement these interface for us to be able to use `Auth::attempt()` method, my question now is how then do we (newbies) know what to implement and what not to implement, or what any of these interfaces  even do.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. It's a laravel's requirement. The **User** model is generated by default for you. If you do not need to implement  the interface's methods, just add them empty in your **User** class. 
And of course, in your case, what to extend or implement will be shown as errors on startup. Reading them carefully can give you all the asnwers.

Also, if you want to use different User Authentication features, or extend the existing ones, you can look some info [here in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication)